# Could not find setter for field on class when using Transformers

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my hibernate application,I have an embeddable class as follows

```
@Embeddable
public class ClientUserId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private Long clientId;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    public ClientUserId() {
    }

    public Long getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(Long clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

and my POJO class

```
public class ClientUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Embedded
    private ClientUserId clientUserId;
    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 32)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 32)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 32)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 64)
    private String email;
    public ClientUser() {
    }

  public ClientUserId getClientUserId() {
    return clientUserId;
}

public void setClientUserId(ClientUserId clientUserId) {
    this.clientUserId = clientUserId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

My sql query is

```
 session.createSQLQuery("SELECT  user_id as userId,email as email,first_name as firstName,last_name as lastName,user_name as userName FROM users").
addScalar("email", new StringType()).addScalar("firstName", new StringType()).addScalar("lastName", new StringType()).addScalar("userName", 
new StringType()).addScalar("userId", new LongType()).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ClientUser.class)).list();
```

In my sql query I am fetching a result set from a table user(same structure of ClientUser table except one field clientId)and transform to class called ClientUser.
Since ClientUserId is Embedded I am getting error as `Could not find setter for userId on class`
How can I resolve this?

Comment: That sounds like a really, really bad idea: the users of the methods returning ClientUser will assume that you're returning real, attached, ClientUser entities with a complete ID and not incomplete, detached objects. You should return a different kind of object. Why don't you map the users table to a User entity? Anyway, just don't use aliasToBean and loop through the rows, creating a new POJO for each row.